# TextChangedEvent does not fire when textbox changes or not

Tags: c#, xaml, events

I am having a difficult time pinpointing what am I doing wrong here. My logic is to run the stored procedure (`UpdateRate`) only if a textbox changes. If there is no change in the textbox, just skip the stored procedure for that row of information and move to the next one.

Can someone please help me figure this out? I have tried everything. Keep in mind that I am new at this and might not fully understand complicated answers.

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : 
{
    internal static string oldAvgRate;
    internal static string oldOTRate;
    internal static string ratetype;
    internal static string rtOT;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
        string sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        MySqlCommand avgRate = new MySqlCommand("Select ID, DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, Amount, Description from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Hourly Wages' and DateTo >= @sDate", connection);
        avgRate.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sDate", sDate));

        MySqlCommand otRate = new MySqlCommand("Select ID, DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, Amount, Description from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average OT Hourly Wages' and DateTo >= @sDate", connection);
        otRate.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sDate", sDate));

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader AvgR = avgRate.ExecuteReader();

            while (AvgR.Read())
            {
                txtAHW.Text = AvgR["Amount"].ToString(); 
                dfAHW.Text = AvgR["DateFrom"].ToString();
                dtAHW.Text = AvgR["DateTo"].ToString();
                txtcommAHW.Text = AvgR["Description"].ToString();

                oldAvgRate = txtAHW.Text = AvgR["Amount"].ToString();
                ratetype = AvgR["RateType"].ToString();
            }

            AvgR.Close();
            AvgR.Dispose();

            MySqlDataReader OtR = otRate.ExecuteReader();

            while (OtR.Read())
            {
                txtOTHW.Text = OtR["Amount"].ToString();
                dfOTHW.Text = OtR["DateFrom"].ToString();
                dtOTHW.Text = OtR["DateTo"].ToString();
                txtcommOTHW.Text = OtR["Description"].ToString();

                oldOTRate = txtOTHW.Text = OtR["Amount"].ToString();
                rtOT = OtR["RateType"].ToString();
            }   

            OtR.Close();
            OtR.Dispose();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

        private string UpdateRate(string dateFrom, string newRate, string oldRate, string ratetype, string description)
        {
            string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;Initial Catalog='';username=;password=";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newRate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldRate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_RateType", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ratetype;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_Description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = description;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();              
                connection.Close();
                return newRate;            
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private bool txtAHWHasChangedFlag;
        private bool txtOTHWHasChangedFlag;

        private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {        
            var control = sender as TextBox;

            if (control.Name == "txtAHW" )
                txtAHWHasChangedFlag = true;
            else if (control.Name == "txtOTHW")
                txtOTHWHasChangedFlag = true;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtAHWHasChangedFlag) //True regardless if changes are made in the textbox or not :(
            {
            oldAvgRate = UpdateRate(dfAHW.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtAHW.Text, oldAvgRate, ratetype, txtcommAHW.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

            if (txtOTHWHasChangedFlag) //True regardless if changes are made in the textbox or not :(
            {
            oldOTRate = UpdateRate(dfOTHW.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtOTHW.Text, oldOTRate, rtOT, txtcommOTHW.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

            if (!txtAHWHasChangedFlag && !txtOTHWHasChangedFlag)
            {    
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing has changed", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
            }
        }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAHW" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtOTHW" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler"/>
```

I have set 2 breakpoints inside inside btnSave_Click on the if statements, started the solution, changed one of the textboxes and notice that whatever I do, both statements result in `True`. Even if I disable my textboxes and click on the save button, I still get `True` instead of `False`. When I attempt to debug I notice the following error on the TextChangedEvent, for one of the textboxes that I change:

[image]

I would really appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

**Attempt based on @user2107843 answer.** It solves my initial problem, but when I click save the second time, it runs both stored procedures instead of only the one that as changed. So if I change txtAHW and then click save, it works, it only runs the stored procedure for txtAHW. If right after that I change txtOHW as well, the stored procedure runs for both instead for running only for txtOHW. My logic here is that txtAHW has already been saved so no need to run again. Can some help me improve this:

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{        
    var control = sender as TextBox;

    if (control.Name == "txtAHW")

        if (oldAvgRate != txtAHW.Text && oldAvgRate != null)
            txtAHWHasChangedFlag = true;
        else
            txtAHWHasChangedFlag = false;
    else if (control.Name == "txtOTHW")
        if (oldOTRate != txtOTHW.Text && oldOTRate != null)
            txtOTHWHasChangedFlag = true;
        else
            txtOTHWHasChangedFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: The code assigns the Text property of these boxes in the constructor, so the bools are always true.  No sign of ever setting back to false, so they are true forever.

Comment: Thank you for your help Hans. This sounds like the solution to my problem. Can you please show me how can I set them back to false? I would be grateful for an example.

Comment: Answers and solutions don't belong in the question. If you think this is worth keeping around, you can post it as an answer instead.

Comment: I agree with you. However it doesn't belong in an answer either. I still need get in to fully work and that solution partially solves my problem. I still need an improvement on top of it. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make false in textChangedEventHandler

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {        
            var control = sender as TextBox;

            if (control.Name == "txtAHW" )

                if(oldAvgRate != txtAHW.Text && oldAvgRate !=null)
                   txtAHWHasChangedFlag = true;
                 else
                   txtAHWHasChangedFlag = false
            else if (control.Name == "txtOTHW")
                txtOTHWHasChangedFlag = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It looks like the right approach. However, I still get the bool True even if there are no changes. I just don't get it. Can you please advise on what might be going on?

Comment: first time you will get true because your oldAvgRate will be null for the first time.Since textChangedEventHandler will be evaluated first.so have a null condition check. if(oldAvgRate != txtAHW.Text && oldAvgRate !=null )

Comment: This is tremendous help!!! Thank you so much, I can't believe we finally got to the bottom of this. There's one more thing that would be really helpful and I would be grateful for your help...

Comment: The behavior now is like this: If nothing changes, no stored procedure is run. If I change txtAHW, the stored procedure is run only for AvgRate and not for OTRate(exactly what I want). There's only one part that needs to be taken care of and I don't know how. If I change txtAHW and click save everything works correctly. Then, if I change txtOTHW and click save again, it runs for both. I only want it to run for the second one because txtAHW has already been changed and saved, no need to run the store procedure again for that row. Can you please advise? Please see my updated question.

Comment: you have to do the same condition check for txtOTHW also.Accept the answer too.

Comment: Thank you for all your support. I do check the same condition for txtOTHW also but it still doesn't address the problem described above. Can you please have a look at the end of my question. We're 90% there and I would really like to understand how to get it to work correctly on the second save. What else am I missing?

Comment: In your save_click after saving make both the flag to false.

Comment: Can you please show me how by editing your answer? I have not idea where to start.

Comment: in your btnsave_click after the messagebox.show.. make the flag you are checking to false.(txtAHWHasChangedFlag = false)

Comment: Man, you are a genius! Thank you for saving the rest of my week. I am so grateful for your help and this community.